# cannot tar on Mac?

Tags: macos, tar

I am trying to compress a log file directory on my mac. The log directory exists.

For example /var/logs/my_log_dir/

I am trying to run something like:

```
$ tar –cpzf x.tar.gz /var/logs/my_log_dir
```

I also tried other variations such as compressing only one of the files in the log dir - no luck. All I get from my mac is:

```
Usage:
  List:    tar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: tar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  tar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    tar --help
```

Thoughts?

Comment: @mouviciel: You should make that an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using -p doesn't make sense in the context of compression, since you're already shoving in whatever permissions are on the files by default. When extracting, however, you can use the -p flag if you're concerned about permissions.

Compress: tar –czvf x.tar.gz /var/logs/my_log_dir

Extract: tar –xpzvf x.tar.gz

Comment: I am not sure what was going on on my mac. I guess a typo somewhere or some issue between running it with sudo vs. non-sudo. I got it to work on both mac and cloud vm. Above method is right/works.

Answer (score 2):

`-p` option (preserve file permissions) works in `x` mode only.